# Selecting a particular number in an array using rand

Tags: c, arrays, random

I have written a code for selecting a number in an array using `rand()`. The function rand_range function selects a random number between the minimum number in the array and total sum of array elements. The array array elements are added starting from the first element and an element is selected if the sum exceeds the random number generated. This is repeated until the required number of selection.
This program is being called inside another loop so it is running several times. But the problem is it is running successfully for initial calls but then for later calls it is going into infinite loop and not breaking.

```
loop: while (1)                                     
{   
    random=rand_range(minimum,total);
    chk=0;
    for(i=0;i<npop;i++)
    {
        chk+=obj[i];   
        if(chk>=random)
        {
            selectedix=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<countselected;i++)
    {
        if(selectedix==previx[i])
            goto loop;
    }

    previx[countselected]=selectedix;
    selectedarr[selectedix]=obj[selectedix]; //selected array
    countselected+=1;

    if (countselected==npop)  
        break;
}
```

Please help as I am not able to understand the reason why it is running for some calls and not for other calls.

Comment: you may need to simplify this as there are places it could be going wrong we can't see. How is chk intialized, for example. What is *obj's type? int? possibly this is an off by one error and obj[] has size of only npop.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your code properly I understand what it is saying.
You are essentially sorting a list of numbers probabilistically, based on the distribution/histogram in obj.

This looks fine:

```
loop: while (1)                                       
{
    random=rand_range(minimum,total);
    chk=0;

    for(i=0;i<npop;i++)    
    {
        chk+=obj[i];
        if(chk>=random)
        {
            selectedix=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<countselected; i++)
        if(selectedix==previx[i])
            goto loop;

    previx[countselected]=selectedix;
    selectedarr[selectedix]=obj[selectedix];
    countselected++;

    //if countselected was not initialised to zero
    //an infinite loop could occur here
    printf("%d", &countselected);
    if (countselected==(npop-1))
        break;
    }
}
```

Until some obj[i] == 0 - chk will never stop on it! Alternatively, a small value will cause a long loop. Also if obj[0] is less than minimum, there will be a problem.

Comment: The code was a part of my program, I had copied directly from it so it wasn't clear i guess. Sorry for that. Please check the code now and tell me the prob.

Comment: @Sourav is it possible that at some point npop is less than countselected? in that case the loop would continue. test for this with `if (countselected>=npop)`

Comment: No npop is not less than countselected. npop is the number of data to be selected from obj[], i want the loop to break as soon as countselected==npop and so that condition has been put for break.

Comment: @SouravMandal see my edit - there will be an infinite loop whenever selectedix==previx[i]

Comment: That is to make sure that a data is not selected twice. It won't be an infinite loop, it will loop till the selectedix is a number that is not already present in previx[]. previx[] is storing indexes of all the previously selected data.

Comment: @SouravMandal between goto loop; and the next time the for loop is reached, there is no access to previx[i]. maybe loop: is in the wrong spot

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are telling, can you please edit the code

Comment: So you mean to say loop: label is to be placed above while(1)? But placing it in front of while(1) is one and the same thing isn't it?

Comment: @SouravMandal no i was just reformatting - please read the annotations carefully

Comment: for(i=0; i<=countselected; i++) in place of for(i=0; i<countselected; i++) ?

Comment: @SouravMandal what is intended behaviour when i is in previx?

Comment: Control jumps back to loop: label i.e all the previous checking is done again

Comment: @SouravMandal my bad - you want a new rand? until chk has stopped at each index?

Comment: yeah a new random is being generated rand_range function between the minimum value of the array and sum of all the values of the array until chk has stopped at each index

Comment: @SouravMandal and every obj[i] is > zero, and the first one is > than minimum? Maybe one obj[i] is very small, so it takes a long time. try printing all obj[i] out as you go

Comment: countselected has been initialized before the while loop. yes the array range is quite large, but still it is working fine for the initial runs, the problem of infinite loop is coming after few runs. also the number of runs after which this problem arises is random

Comment: @SouravMandal i am suggesting that it is not so much an infinite loop, as just a really really long looop because some values are small. please log all values of obj[i] as there is no visible error here

Comment: but if that is the case why is it working fine for initial runs? it must be a long loop for all the runs right?

Comment: is obj[i] changing at all? do you reset previx? do you reset countselected?

Comment: yeah obj[i] is changing, but just now I found something, after some runs the countselected is not going upto npop, it is stuck, may be in a very long loop

Comment: @SouravMandal please make sure previx is reset and obj[] > 0, this is only possible cause

Comment: previx is getting reset before the loop. and yes obj[]>0